# Tag based co-occurrence image clustering

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, similarity, google-vision

I labeled lots of object images using Google Vision API. Using those labels (list in pickle [here](https://github.com/Matt52/data-research/blob/master/data/labels.pkl)), I created a label co-occurrence matrix (download as numpy array [here](https://github.com/Matt52/data-research/blob/master/data/cooccurrence.npy)). Size of the matrix is 2195x2195.

Loading the data:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
with open('labels.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    labels = pickle.load(f)

cooccurrence = np.load('cooccurrence.npy')
```

I would like to use a clustering analysis to define reasonable amount of clusters (defined as lists of Vision labels) which would represent some objects (e.g. cars, shoes, books, ....). I do not know what is the right number of clusters.

I tried hierarchical clustering algorithm available in scikit-learn:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)

#creating non-symetrical "similarity" matrix:
occurrences = cooccurrence.diagonal().copy()
similarities = cooccurrence / occurrences[:,None]

#clustering:
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
clusters = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=200, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward').fit_predict(similarities)

#results in pandas:
df_clusters = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': clusters.tolist(), 'label': labels})
df_clusters_grouped = df_clusters.groupby(['cluster']).agg({'label': [len, list]})
df_clusters_grouped.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df_clusters_grouped.columns.values]
df_clusters_grouped.rename(columns = {'label len': 'cluster_size', 'label list': 'cluster_labels'}, inplace=True)
df_clusters_grouped.sort_values(by=['cluster_size'], ascending=False)
```

Like this, I was able to create 200 clusters where one can look like:

```
["Racket", "Racquet sport", "Tennis racket", "Rackets", "Tennis", "Racketlon", "Tennis racket accessory", "Strings"]
```

This somehow works, but I would rather use some soft clustering method which would be able to assign one label to multiple clusters (for instance "leather" might make sense for shoes and wallets). Also, I had to define number of clusters (200 in my example code), which is something I would rather get as a result (if possible).

I was also playing with [hdbscan](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html#distance-matrices), [k-clique](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.kclique.k_clique_communities.html) and [Gaussian mixture models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) but I did not come up with any better output.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering methods such as AgglomerativeClustering of sklearn require a **data matrix** as input. With `metric="precomputed"` you can also use a **distance matrix** (*it* for k-means and Gaussian mixture modeling, these do need coordinate data).

You, however, have a cooccurrence or *simarity* matrix. These values have the opposite meaning, so you'll have to identify an appropriate transformation (for example occurrences-cooccurrences). Treating the cooccurrence matrix as data matrix (and then using Euclidean distance - that is what you do) works to some extend but has very weird semantics and is *not* recommended.